# TypeError: sally is undefined

Tags: javascript

Help me please, i have error "TypeError: sally is undefined";
I don`t understand why.

```
function Person(name,age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.species = "Homo Sapiens";
};

var sally = Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
var holden = Person("Holden Bowles", 16);

console.log("sally's species is " + sally.species + " and she is " +  
sally.age);
console.log("holden's species is " + holden.species + " and he is " +   
holden.age);
```

Comment: Try `sally  = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);`
I guess you missed the 'new' keyword.

Comment: *I don`t understand why* any javascript beginners tutorial would have helped you understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new object you **have to** call constructor with **new** operator

```
objectName = new objectType(param1 [,param2] ...[,paramN])
```

See [MDN new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for more information about new operator.

In your current implementation calling :

```
var sally = Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
```

`this` within executing Person constructor would be **window object** ( it should be noted that `this` would be object in which context function was defined, i assume it's window object).

So, you have to simply add **new**  operator prior calling constructor to pass desired context and get valid `this` within constructor:

```
var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
```

Comment: To be pedantic looking at that code you can’t know what `this` will be; it might be the `window` object but it depends if it’s executed in the browser and in which context.

Comment: @bfontaine thanks for noting that moment.

Comment: @zok1995 you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `new` operator:

```
var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
var holden = new Person("Holden Bowles", 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t prefix `Person(…)` with `new`, the function is called and its return value is assigned to `sally`. In your case the function returns nothing (`undefined`) so both `sally` and `holden` are set to `undefined`.

What you want is create an object with the `new` keyword:

```
var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
var holden = new Person("Holden Bowles", 16);
```